# If and Switch statements; Is there an easier way of producing this code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement, switch-statement

My code is as follows:

```
namespace Calculation
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a system to calculate speed, distance or time.");
        Console.WriteLine("1 = Speed - 2 = Distance - 3 = time");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter which calculation you would like to perform. 1, 2 or 3");

        string userCalculation = Console.ReadLine();
        int Calculation = int.Parse(userCalculation);

        if(Calculation < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number greater than or equal to 1 but less than 3.");
        }

        if (Calculation > 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number less than 3 but greater than or equal to 1.");
        }

        else
        {
            switch (Calculation)
            {
                //This statement calculates speed.
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chose to calculate speed. S = D/T");

                    Console.WriteLine("To work this out you need to firstly enter your distance in metres");
                    string userDistance = Console.ReadLine();
                    int Distance = int.Parse(userDistance);

                    Console.WriteLine("Now enter your time in seconds.");
                    string userTime = Console.ReadLine();
                    int Time = int.Parse(userTime);

                    Console.WriteLine("Your speed is " + Distance / Time + " m/s");
                    Console.WriteLine("In MPH this is " + Distance / Time * 2.23 + "MPH");
                    break;

                //This statement calculates distance.
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chose to calculate distance. D = SxT");

                    Console.WriteLine("To work this out you need to firstly enter your speed");
                    string userSpeed = Console.ReadLine();
                    int Speed = int.Parse(userSpeed);

                    Console.WriteLine("Now enter your time in hours.");
                    string userTime1 = Console.ReadLine();
                    double Time1 = double.Parse(userTime1);

                    Console.WriteLine("Your Distance is " + Speed * Time1 + " miles");
                    break;

                //This statement calculates time.
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chose to calculate Time. T = D/S");

                    Console.WriteLine("To work this out you need to firstly enter your distance in miles.");
                    string userMiles = Console.ReadLine();
                    int Miles = int.Parse(userMiles);

                    Console.WriteLine("Now enter your Speed in MPH.");
                    string userSpeed2 = Console.ReadLine();
                    double Speed2 = double.Parse(userSpeed2);

                    Console.WriteLine("Your Time is " + Miles / Speed2 + "hours.");
                    Console.WriteLine("This would be " + Miles / Speed2 * 60 + " minutes");
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: This type of question is more suited for Code Review SE (please read their "How to Ask" before posting). Its not on-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about doing a code review of working code.

Comment: Um... well with a bit of change in the question it can be a general beginner question rather than a code review, but, yea.

Comment: Side note: since both `Distance` and `time` are of type`int` (`case 1:`) `Distance / Time` will cause *integer division* problem, e.g. `5 / 8 == 0` change `Distance` or `time` or both to be `double`

Comment: Certainly! Take a look at how to use functions, and the `default` case for `switch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove one if statement it is not very diffrent from die other if statement. replace it by this one:

```
        if (Calculation < 1 || Calculation > 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number greater than or equal to 1 but less than 3.");
        }
```

Create Two funtions to return user input one for int and the second for the double return type.

```
    private int GetIntUserInput()
    {
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        int convertedUserInput = int.Parse(userInput);

        return convertedUserInput;
    }

    private double GetDoubleUserInput()
    {
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        double convertedUserInput = double.Parse(userInput);

        return convertedUserInput;
    }
```

And I should move the calculations to a funtion as well
You also can use an enum for better readability.

```
    enum Options
    {
        Speed,
        Time,
        Distance
    } 

     //example
      Options calculation = (Options)Calculation; //cast user input number 
                                                  // to Option enum 
      switch (calculation)
      {
       case options.Distance:
           // some code
       break;
       case options.Speed:
           // some code
       break;
      }
```

Comment: you cannot have two overloads of `GetUserInput()` that only differ by return type

Comment: ai, Dit not see that one copy paste

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for a better maintainablity index, you better make those 3 algorithms into seperate functions and call them, or at least the calculations.
About the if/switch, you can use a `default:` case at the end of your switch,

```
default:
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number greater than or equal to 1 but less than 3.");
break;
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: wow, someone actually downvoted this.  Stackoverflow users never cease to amuse me.

Comment: @MikeNakis Yea, things happen, just let them be! btw I'm glad I could help.

Comment: For those that have helped your guidance is much appreciated. I have only been programming for a couple of weeks so all criticism and input is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

As a start, perhaps something like this (air code):

```
case 1:
    Console.WriteLine("You have chose to calculate speed. S = D/T");

    int Distance = GetNumericInput("To work this out you need to firstly enter your distance in metres");
    int Time = GetNumericInput("Now enter your time in seconds.");

    Console.WriteLine("Your speed is " + Distance / Time + " m/s");
    Console.WriteLine("In MPH this is " + Distance / Time * 2.23 + "MPH");
    break;
```

Which uses this function (air code, needs error handling):

```
string GetNumericInput(string prompt)
{
    Console.WriteLine(prompt;
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    int inputNumeric = int.Parse(input);
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Integer division: `Distance = 20;`, `Time = 25;` and `"Your speed is 0"`

Answer (score 0):

My usual approach for organising code like this is to make each case into a class, and add those classes into a dictionary against their case value, e.g.:

```
public interface ICalculation
{
    void Run();
}

public class SpeedCalculation
    : ICalculation
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have chose to calculate speed. S = D/T");

        Console.WriteLine("To work this out you need to firstly enter your distance in metres");
        string userDistance = Console.ReadLine();
        int Distance = int.Parse(userDistance);

        Console.WriteLine("Now enter your time in seconds.");
        string userTime = Console.ReadLine();
        int Time = int.Parse(userTime);

        Console.WriteLine("Your speed is " + Distance / Time + " m/s");
        Console.WriteLine("In MPH this is " + Distance / Time * 2.23 + "MPH");
    }
}

...more ICalculation types...

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var caseDictionary = new Dictionary<int, ICalculation>
        {
            {1, new SpeedCalculation()},
            {2, new DistanceCalculation()},
            {3, new TimeCalculation()}
        };

        Console.WriteLine("This is a system to calculate speed, distance or time.");
        Console.WriteLine("1 = Speed - 2 = Distance - 3 = time");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter which calculation you would like to perform. 1, 2 or 3");

        string userCalculation = Console.ReadLine();
        int Calculation = int.Parse(userCalculation);

        if(!caseDictionary.ContainsKey(Calculation))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 3 (inclusive).");
        }
        else
        {
            caseDictionary[Calculation].Run();
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you options for organising the code as you like with inheritance or abstractions, makes it easy to add new cases (even programmatically), and you could make the main method more flexible (e.g. the line "1 = Speed - 2 = Distance - 3 = time" could be generated from the contents of the dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the following:

```
class Program
{
    private class MenuOption
    {
        public string Description { get; }
        public Action Run { get; }

        public MenuOption(string description, Action run)
        {
            Description = description;
            Run = run;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int option;
        var menuOptions = buildMenuOptions();

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"This is a system to calculate: {string.Join(", ", menuOptions.Values.Take(menuOptions.Count-1).Select(o => o.Description))}");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" - ", menuOptions.Select(kv => $"{kv.Key} = {kv.Value.Description}")));
            Console.WriteLine($"Please enter which calculation you would like to perform. [{string.Join(", ", menuOptions.Keys)}]");
        } while (!tryValidateUserOption(menuOptions, out option));

        menuOptions[option].Run();
        Console.Write("Press key to exit... ");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IDictionary<int, MenuOption> buildMenuOptions() =>
        new Dictionary<int, MenuOption>() { { 1, new MenuOption("Speed", () => runSpeedOption()) },
                                            { 2, new MenuOption("Distance", () => runDistanceOption()) },
                                            { 3, new MenuOption("Time", () => runTimeOption())},
                                            { 4, new MenuOption("Quit", () => { return; }) } };

    private static bool tryValidateUserOption(IDictionary<int, MenuOption> options, out int selectedOption)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (!int.TryParse(input, out selectedOption) ||
            !options.ContainsKey(selectedOption))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid option. Please try again.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static void runTimeOption()
    {
        int miles;
        double speed;
        Console.WriteLine("You have chose to calculate Time. T = D/S.");
        getUserInput("To work this out you need to firstly enter your distance in miles.", 0, int.MaxValue, out miles);
        getUserInput("Now enter your Speed in MPH.", 0, double.MaxValue, out speed);
        Console.WriteLine("Your Time is " + miles / speed + " hours.");
        Console.WriteLine("This would be " + miles / speed * 60 + " minutes");
    }

    private static void runDistanceOption()
    {
        int speed;
        double time;
        Console.WriteLine("You have chose to calculate distance. D = SxT.");
        getUserInput("To work this out you need to firstly enter your speed.", 0, int.MaxValue, out speed);
        getUserInput("Now enter your time in hours.", 0, double.MaxValue, out time);
        Console.WriteLine("Now enter your time in hours.");
        Console.WriteLine("Your Distance is " + speed * time + " miles");
    }

    private static void runSpeedOption()
    {
        int distance, time;
        Console.WriteLine("You have chose to calculate speed. S = D/T");
        getUserInput("To work this out you need to firstly enter your distance in metres.", 0, int.MaxValue, out distance);
        getUserInput("Now enter your time in seconds.", 0, int.MaxValue, out time);
        Console.WriteLine("Your speed is " + distance / time + " m/s");
        Console.WriteLine("In MPH this is " + distance / time * 2.23 + " MPH");
    }


    private static void getUserInput(string message, int lowerInclusiveBound, int upperExclusiveBound, out int value)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (int.TryParse(input, out value) &&
                value >= lowerInclusiveBound &&
                value < upperExclusiveBound)
                return;

            Console.WriteLine("Input is not a valid value. Please try again.");
        }
    }

    private static void getUserInput(string message, double lowerInclusiveBound, double upperExclusiveBound, out double value)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (double.TryParse(input, out value) &&
                value >= lowerInclusiveBound &&
                value < upperExclusiveBound)
                return;

            Console.WriteLine("Input is not a valid value. Please try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Things to note:

1. Don't hard code the menu. Make it flexible, that way adding options is easy; look how much it took to add a fourth option.
2. If the menu is not set, you can't hard code options with ifs and switches. Use a dictionary with the option number as a key. Store as value a delegate to the action you want to perform.
3. Try to not repeate code. Extract all common functionality to helper methods that can be reused; consider changing all inputs to double to reduce pesky code duplication validating ints and doubles.